# How to parameterize SQL Server script

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to convert `MyUser`, `MyPassword` and `MyDatabase` within the following SQL Server script into parameters?

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT name  
     FROM master.sys.server_principals
     WHERE name = 'MyUser')
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN MyUser WITH PASSWORD = 'MyPassword'
END

CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase;
GO

USE MyDatabase;

CREATE USER MyUser FOR LOGIN MyUser;  
GO   

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'MyUser'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `GO` is a script command, not a T-SQL keyword. This script can only run in `SSMS` or `sqlcmd`. If you want to run this eg during deployment, use [Scripting variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-with-scripting-variables?view=sql-server-2017) and pass their values as parameters to the `sqlcmd` command that executes the script file

Comment: These scripted commands are necessary to configure a database for our business application. Since I have to do this regularly, I'd like to automate it without changing the mentioned properties at several places.

Comment: FYI `sp_addrolemember ` has been deprecated since SQL Server 2012 (or prior) iirc.

Comment: Use scripting variables and sqlcmd then

Comment: User and password, yes. Database, I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may have found out, you have to use literals for tasks like this. As a result you have to use dynamic SQL and **safely** inject the values For example, for the login (assuming the parameter values have been set in an SP):

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM sys.syslogins
               WHERE name = @MyLogin)
    SET @SQL = N'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@MyLogin) + N' WITH PASSWORD = N' + QUOTENAME(@MyPassword,'''') + N';';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

If the login already exists, then `@SQL` will have a value of `NULL` and won't be created.

As a result, your final SP will look something like this:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.SetupLogin @MyLogin sysname, @MyDatabase sysname, @MyPassword nvarchar(128) AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM sys.syslogins
                   WHERE name = @MyLogin)
        SET @SQL = N'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@MyLogin) + N' WITH PASSWORD = N' + QUOTENAME(@MyPassword,'''') + N';';


    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

    SET @SQL = N'CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME (@MyDatabase) + N';'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

    SET @SQL = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME (@MyDatabase) + N';' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'CREATE USER ' + QUOTENAME(@MyLogin) + N' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@MyLogin) + N';' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER ' + QUOTENAME(@MyLogin) + N';'; --sp_addrolemember is deprecated, stop using it.
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

END;
```